Partial derivatives "split" over $\mathbb R$
Kaplansky's book Fields and Rings, page 30, implicitly contains the following question.

For which fields $K$ does the following statement hold true for every polynomial $g\in K[X]$: If $g$ splits over $K$ then its derivative $g'$ splits over $K$.

This is, for instance, true for real closed fields, e.g., for $\mathbb R$ and the paper A weak version of Rolle's Theorem by Thomas C. Craven in Proc. AMS 125:11, p.  3147–3153, contains further treatment of the problem.
I am interested in the multivariate analogue of this problem over $\mathbb R$ and I could not find anything about it. Let me make the question precise:
Question: Let $g \in \mathbb R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ be a polynomial that factors over $\mathbb R$ into polynomials that are irreducible over $\mathbb C$. Do all partial derivatives $\frac{\partial g}{\partial X_i}$ factor over $\mathbb R$ into polynomials irreducible over $\mathbb C$?
This arises naturally in real birational geometry. The following can be made precise and leads to the above question: Are certain hypersurfaces that are normal crossing over $\mathbb R$ also normal crossing over $\mathbb C$?
Thanks in advance for your help!

The normal crossing hypersufaces are way over my head, but the question in bold font is markedly more mundane.
$x^2+y+y^3$ is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$, but $\frac\partial{\partial y}(x^2+y+y^3)=3y^2+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb R[x,y]$ and reducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$. For the specific case $\frac\partial{\partial x}(x^2+y+y^3)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$, but I would assume that, if extra-credit were needed, it's possible to find two polynomials $f,g$ of degree $3$ such that $f'$ and $g'$ are irreducible over $\Bbb R$ and $f(x)+g(y)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$.
Added: $g(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_2)(x_1^2+x_2^2-x_1x_2+1)$ is already factored in $\Bbb C[x_1,x_2]$, but $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=3x_i^2+1$.
